# Euler's Approximation

Tags: python, math, differential-equations, calculus

I'm trying to make a program for Euler's Approximation for a differential equation(I got a problem in a book telling me to).I managed to write something that works for everything(that I've tested at least) but it fails at step = 0,1 for some reason...
Here is the code:

```
from math import pow as p

y0: int = 3

h = input("Step size:")
h =float(h)
h1 = h
x_n=0
while x_n < (1):
    yn = y0 + h*(3*(p(x_n ,2))*(2-y0))
    x_n=h1
    h1=h1+h
    y0=yn
else:
    print(yn)

# h(1),f(1)=3
# h(0.1),f(1)=2,39279
# h(0.01),f(1)=2.37011
# h(0.001),f(1)=2.36810
```

It works for h=1, h=0.5, h=0.2, h=0.05, h=0.01, h=0.001 and so on... For some reason it only fails when h=0.1.

The differential equation in question is y'=3(x^2)(2-y)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: when you say "fails" you mean that its getting the wrong answer in the final `yn`?

Comment: Your code is correct, the result for h = 0.1 is 2.274955739773159. Are you comparing it to the result of a book? Maybe you have implemented some wrong code, check the equation and the initial parameters.

Comment: I have used online calculators for the euler approximation and slader.com if you know the site and they both say that for h=0.1 the result should be 2.36 or something similar...

Comment: https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/differential-equations/euler-method-calculator/?f=6x%5E2-3x%5E2y&type=h&h=0.1&x=0&y=3&e=1&steps=on this is the site i used to check my code.

Comment: This is slader post i used to verify as well,it was done by some guy with another euler calculator.https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780495384175-single-variable-calculus-volume-1-6th-edition/615/exercises/25a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It would look better if the variable names have a uniform construction)

If you print out also the time of the last step

```py
for h in [1.0,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05]:
    x_n, y_0 = 0.0, 3.0
    while x_n < (1):
        y_n = y_0 + h*(3*(x_n**2)*(2-y_0))
        x_n = x_n + h
        y_0 = y_n
    else:
        print(f"h={h}: f({x_n:12.10f}) = {y_n:12.10f}")
```

then you find in the result

```
h= 1.00000: f(1.0000000000) = 3.0000000000
h= 0.50000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.6250000000
h= 0.20000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.4261034230
h= 0.10000: f(1.1000000000) = 2.2749557398
h= 0.05000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.3795619396
```

that indeed at `h=0.1` the iteration only stops at `x=1.1`. This is due to the floating point format of the variables, the point `x_n` close to `x=1` can fall shortly below, so that another step is performed. One way to prevent this is to adapt the last step (another is to use a "close-by" comparison)

```py
for h in [1.0,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05]:
    x_n, y_0, x_f = 0.0, 3.0, 1.0
    y_n = y_0
    while x_n < x_f:
        if x_n + 1.001*h > x_f: h = x_f - x_n
        y_n = y_n + h*(3*(x_n**2)*(2-y_n))
        x_n = x_n + h
    else:
        print(f"h={h:8.5f}: f({x_n:12.10f}) = {y_n:12.10f}")
```

which gives the more consistent result

```
h= 1.00000: f(1.0000000000) = 3.0000000000
h= 0.50000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.6250000000
h= 0.20000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.4261034230
h= 0.10000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.3927939140
h= 0.05000: f(1.0000000000) = 2.3795619396
```

---

To explore the influence of the floating point representation of the numbers, print out in long what the floating point numbers really are,

```py
print(", ".join("%20.17f"%x for x in np.cumsum(10*[0.1])))
```

gives

```
0.10000000000000001,  0.20000000000000001,  0.30000000000000004,  
0.40000000000000002,  0.50000000000000000,  0.59999999999999998,  
0.69999999999999996,  0.79999999999999993,  0.89999999999999991,  
0.99999999999999989
```

This shows that the rounding in the last mantissa bit after floating point operations can have rather counter-intuitive results

Comment: Ok thank you! I don't quite understand what you meant by the floating point format and what you said after(i rarely program and when i do if it does what i want i usually move on without improving the code).If you could explain in greater detail I'll greatly appreciate.

Comment: @DaniBaba, by repeatedly adding h onto x_n, you may get small round-off errors that cause the check `x_n < 1 ` to pass when it should not, resulting in you taking one additional step. I would recommend to rather take `n`, the number of timesteps as the input, define `h = x_f/n` and use a `for loop` rather than a `while loop`. This way you will always take the correct amount of steps.

Answer (score 2):

there is no problem with your code.
(also you can use `**` instead of `pow`; e.g. `pow(2,3) = 2**3 = 8`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help,what is the graph supposed to represent?Also i know about ** i just prefer pow :D.The problem is that when i look online calculator for euler approximation it's giving me 2.36 or something similar and the same with slader.com(it's a website to check the answers of problems)

Comment: sorry, should have labeled the axis. . The x-axis is the `h` and y axis is `yn`. 
The analytical solution is y=exp(-x^3) + 2 which means yn = y(1) = 2 + 1/e. and your solution is correct,provided that the stepsize is small enough.